# How to prove that a sphere without two points is homeomorphic to a hyperbolic cylinder in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves

If I understood correctly, then a sphere without two points is the same as a standard cylinder. how then to prove that a hyperbolic cylinder is homeomorphic to a standard one? I have no idea how to correctly construct a mapping, especially from a hyperbolic cylinder to a standard one

Comment: What do you mean by a hyperbolic cylinder? A hyperboloid of one sheet? And, of course, by "the same as" you mean homeomorphic.

Comment: By hyperbolic cylinder I mean $X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | y^2 = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)\}$, where $x_1 \neq x_2$. And yes, by the same as I mean homeomorphic

Comment: You need to edit your post to include the definition. This is quite non-standard. And you mean $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2$, of course. Without loss of generality, we can assume $y^2=x(x-1)$. You want to prove this is homeomorphic to $\Bbb C^* = \Bbb C-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what your background or tools are. The easiest way for me to see this is to think about the closure of the algebraic curve $y^2=x(x-1)$ in $\Bbb CP^2$. By projecting on the $x$-axis, you get a branched $2$-fold cover of $\Bbb CP^1$, branched at the two points $x=0$ and $x=1$. (The point at infinity has two preimages.) Such a branched cover (by, for example, [the Riemann-Hurwitz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula)) is another copy $X$ of $\Bbb CP^1$ [think of the usual branched cover $z\rightsquigarrow z^2$, branched over $0$ and $\infty$]. But now I must remove two points from $X$, namely the two points lying over $\infty$. So $X=\Bbb CP^1 - \{p,q\} \cong \Bbb C - \{q\}$, and the punctured plane is indeed homeomorphic to a cylinder (think polar coordinates).

**EDIT**: Here is a more concrete approach. By considering the pencil of lines through the origin (slope $t$), we parametrize the curve by
$$x=\frac1{1-t^2},\quad y=\frac t{1-t^2}, \quad t\in\Bbb CP^1-\{\pm1\}.$$
This parametrization gives the explicit homeomorphism to $\Bbb C^*$. If you so wish, you can compose with an automorphism (linear fractional transformation) of $\Bbb CP^1$ carrying $0,\infty$ to $\pm 1$, and then the parametrization will be explicitly by $\Bbb C-\{0\}$.

Comment: Now I think I don’t really understand how $X$ looks like. How should I visualise it?

Comment: $X$ is a topological sphere. It is a smooth conic in $\Bbb CP^2$. You can find a rational parametrization of it, as with any smooth conic.

Comment: What is a slope $t$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: It’s a complex ratio $y/x$ of complex numbers. In other words, we are setting $y=tx$.

Comment: And why is $t$ from $\mathbb{C}P^1$ then?

Comment: I wrote it that way because in projective geometry we think of a pencil of lines as a $\Bbb CP^1$. If you prefer to write $\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, that's fine, too.